# How to (manually) set the date in a letter?

Tags: letters, date

I'm trying to start writing letters with Latex, starting with the `letter` document class:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.

% The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
% the typesetting of the document.
\ldots 

That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\ps

P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
\url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.

\encl{Copyright permission form}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This prints today's date. While this is nice and probably mostly one's intention, there are obviously cases where the date should not coincide with the last Latex run.

How is it possible (what are recommended ways) of setting the date in this letter to, say, 21. October 2041?

Comment: `\date{21.~October 2041}` will also print the dot after “21”.

Comment: This has nothing to do with letters. This is just how you always set the date in LaTeX.

Comment: Why have you capitalised 'Faithfully'?

Comment: @cfr well yes it does: letter puts in the date automatically (what happens under the TeX-hood is another question). Re 2nd comment: spelling mistake which got copy-and-pasted with the rest of the MWE :-)

Comment: The standard classes all put in the date automatically. Nothing special about `letter`.

Comment: exception that proves the rule? `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\end{document}`

Comment: vs. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{This is an article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add `\date{}` somewhere before `\begin{opening}`.
For instance, in your document:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\date{October 21, 2014}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
...
```

Comment: Note the argument to date doesn't need to be a date - you can also enter a "Location, Data" combination that is customary in some places.

Answer (score 2):

Place it before the letter begins. In other places the date still takes the system defined today's date.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}
\date{October 21, 2041} % <== this is the correct place to put it
\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!